# How to update highchart column bar graph in input change in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, r-highcharter, react-highcharts

I have created one form with column bar graph. By default column graph loaded as per the options. But here, i want to update graph each time whenever i will change the input. In form, I have 5 inputs. I googled and i found few example on pure javascript. However, i want on react functional component. Can anyone just share me some snippet so that i can start writing it..
I used "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.0"
I am new to React Highchart and i really appreciate your response.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger chart updates by changing options state. Please check the below simple example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [firstVal, setFirstVal] = useState(11);
  const [secondVal, setSecondVal] = useState(22);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    series: [{
      type: "column",
      data: []
    }]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setOptions({
      series: [{ data: [firstVal, secondVal] }]
    });
  }, [firstVal, secondVal]);

  return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      <input
        value={firstVal}
        onChange={(e) => setFirstVal(+e.target.value)}
        ...
      />
      <input
        value={secondVal}
        onChange={(e) => setSecondVal(+e.target.value)}
        ...
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-vhpvqr

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react